# How to check the values in columns are empty in excel sheet using jxl

Tags: java, excel, jxl

I need to check the values in columns in excel sheet using jxl.If the first three columns are empty then the fourth column should not empty or if the fourth column is empty then all the  three columns should not be empty.

Please suggest how to do this using jxl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("myfile.xls"));
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getRows(); i++) {
    boolean c1Empty = sheet.getCell(0, i).getContents().isEmpty();
    boolean c2Empty = sheet.getCell(1, i).getContents().isEmpty();
    boolean c3Empty = sheet.getCell(2, i).getContents().isEmpty();
    boolean c4Empty = sheet.getCell(3, i).getContents().isEmpty();
    if (c1Empty && c2Empty && c3Empty && c4Empty) {
        throw new RuntimeException("If the first three columns are empty then the fourth column can not empty.");
    }
    // Redundant
    //if (c4Empty && c1Empty && c2Empty && c3Empty) {
    //    throw new RuntimeException("If the fourth column is empty then all the three columns should not be empty.");
    //}
}
```